# How to update control state in callback event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, icallbackeventhandler

My project in vs2012 asp.netC# **web page**,i have developed a custom web control of **telerik grid batch edit** that implements **ICallbackEventHandler** and fires an event when the callback is invoked.My control fill process is straight from server IcallBack send josn data fill control by bellow syntax:

```
function GridBind(GridID, GridData) {
    var TableView = GridID.get_masterTableView();
    TableView.set_dataSource(GridData); TableView.dataBind();
}
```

But it’s cannot update the control state and does not update the control eidt item label properly several times. Is this a limitation of the modified callback lifecycle or is there some way to make it work?

Comment: Callbacks do not return and store all the data (e.g., ViewState), nor do they go through the entire lifecycle of the page, so it is rarely a good idea to change control properties during a callback.

Comment: rdmptn,thanks for your reply.control which property hold the control state.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but IScriptControls have a ClientState hidden field in addition to the standard data any ASP control puts in the ViewState. Not sure how that would help you, though. Callbacks do not send the viewstate down to the browser, so the next postback from the browser will give your server the old state of the controls, regardless of what you did during the callback. That's what I meant